# Hyperledger fabric enrolling Admin

Tags: sdk, hyperledger-fabric

I am using following code to enroll Admin in Hyperledger fabric

```
fabric_ca_client = new    fabric_CA_Client('https://localhost:3000',tlsOptions , ca.example.com',' crypto_suite);


return fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true); }).then((user_from_store) => {
if (user_from_store && user_fro_store.isEnrolled()) {
    console.log('Successfully loaded admin from persistence');
    admin_user = user_from_store;
    return null;
} else {
    // need to enroll it with CA server
    console.log(' Trying to enroll user since it is not already enrolled')
    return fabric_ca_client.enroll({
      enrollmentID: 'admin',
      enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw'
    }).then((enrollment) => {
      console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"');
      return fabric_client.createUser(
          {   username: 'admin',
              mspid: 'Org1MSP',
              cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate }
   });
    }).then((user) => {
      admin_user = user;
      console.log(admin_user)
      return fabric_client.setUserContext(admin_user);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error('Failed to enroll and persist admin. Error: ' + err.stack ? err.stack : err);
      throw new Error('Failed to enroll admin');
    });
}
```

and my `user_from_store` is returning `null`, hence all the code is Failing please advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure about the address you're using? Is the peer running on port `3000`?

Comment: yes it is local host

Comment: does it make difference?

Comment: I don't mean `localhost` I mean the port. Are you running the CA on port `3000` or port `7054`

Comment: you are right its a different port

Comment: Does changing it to 7054 in the code solve your issue?

Comment: can u also please advise which `store_path` should I use

Comment: `store_path` is the path to your `.hfc-key-store` directory. In most cases it's going to be `~/.hfc-key-store` if you haven't edited any configurations

Comment: I have changed many things. is it the folder with peerOrganizations and ordererOrganisations??

Comment: No that's your `crypto-config/*` directory. You'll have a `.hfc-key-store` directory for the same. Please use the community on rocket chat for your discussion. I think the answer to this question is the wrong port you were using.